# How to write the curl request to get notifies on page feed updates

Tags: node.js, facebook, curl, facebook-graph-api

I need to subscribe the facebook app and the page to get notifies on page feed updates in order to send private replies to visitors comments. for that i need to post a curl command to the following URL

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/${PAGE_ID}/subscribed_apps?subscribed_fields=feed&access_token=${PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}.
```

And I need to receive following json object to my console.

```
{"success": "true"}
```

but I dont receive it. I cannot find whats the error. facebook developer docs as [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/realtime)

I wrote my code as follows. please help me on this

```
    const connectPage = (req, res) => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    try {
      let URL = `https://graph.facebook.com/${PAGE_ID}/subscribed_apps?subscribed_fields=feed&access_token=${PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}`;
      
      request(
        {
          uri: URL,
          method: POST,
         
        },
        (err, res) => {
          if (!err) {
            console.log(res);
            resolve();
          } else {
            reject(err);
            console.log(err);
          }
        }
      );
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: You should be able to send test notifications via the backend, what happens when you do that? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started#configure-webhooks-product

Comment: any log entries on your node server? you do have some console.log entries after all.